# How to display all topics under a group's forum in buddypress?

Tags: wordpress, buddypress, bbpress

I have building buddypress site where user able to discuss under a group. I have installed bbpress with buddypress. So, when user go to detail view of a group, they can see the all topics of forum if they click on the forum section. But I want to do something like that when user go to detail view of a group, all topics of group's forum will be displayed underneath of the description of group. I do not understand which template should I edit or which loop or query should I add into `buddypress/groups/single/home` file.

Comment: Hey, Did you get the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the topics to appear right below the description you'll have to edit the `groups/single/group-header.php` file. That way the topics appear on every group page.

You probably could copy a lot of code from `/plugins/buddypress/bp-templates/bp-legacy/buddypress/groups/single/forum.php`